Creating a Vertical Calendar
Using SAS, is is it possible to use existing date functions and macros to vertically stretch out a calendar data frame?
For example, I want to make a data frame with columns: day, month, year.
This table should contain all days from Dec-1-1999 to Dec-1-2005. I can do this in other software like Python or Excel - but can it be done in SAS?

Variable names can only be 32 chars in sas. But otherwise you can make the same

What code did you try?  Should be pretty simple with a DO loop in a SAS data step.

It's rare to need this sort of calendar table in SAS, because you can normally use date functions or formats to calculate various date values/formats, instead of storing them in a lookup table.
That said, it's straight forward to make a table like this, e.g.:
data mycal ;
  do date="01Jan2024"d to today() ;
    calendar_year=year(date) ;
    calendar_month=month(date) ;
    day=day(date) ;
    dayofweek=weekday(date) ;
    output ;
  end ;
  format date date9. ;
run ;

proc print ;
run ;

If you can describe in English the logic for the remaining variables, I'm happy to add them.
